# I can not log in, I'm in loop

Tags: 14.04, unity, xorg, login, lightdm

I read many solutions but none worked for me.
I need some help, I have the xsession-errors registry

[image: here is]

Already a week ago to install something, fglrx always worked well and everything worked normal but I do not know what happened. The last thing I did was to navigate a bit in Firefox.
Is Ubuntu 14.04 with updates to date

Comment: No, `fglrx` no longer works. Purge it and you should be fine.

Comment: Use the apt-get purge but the problem persists, try even swap between gdm and lightdm and nothing